# How to start using vim with a non-english keyboard

Tags: vim, keyboard

I recently started using git, and by default it would want to use vim. I always wanted to look a bit deeper in this editor, but was always thrown back, only using it if for some reason (such as in case of a near dead Linux system) it was unavoidable. Even now I soon ended up reconfiguring git to use mcedit instead (which I use for programming).

The problem was that OK, I gave the command `:help` to see how I could start. Then in the help system it suggests me to jump to the subject interesting me using `CTRL-]`. And here I am lost. I have a Hungarian keyboard, and simply couldn't find where it excepted to find `]`. So I can just scroll around in a list of topics I can not enter.

This is just the beginning: In general how much such "weird" combinations I may except? And how I could fix those up? An other problem with the Hungarian language is that it has a bunch of extra vowels which have to be mapped on the same amount of keys like English with it's 26 letters (there are 9 extra letters, so 9 keys "lost"!). Would this hinder the use of vim for writing Hungarian text (where I would require these keys to produce the language-specific vowels)?

How this problem could be solved in a way that if I happen to get an English keyboard (for which layout I guess vim was originally designed), I wouldn't have to re-learn the positioning of the keys? (Since I have no English keyboard around I can't try what happens. As I tried neither of the two keys on the left of 'P' would suffice for the `CTRL-]` combination while as far as the layouts I checked the second should be it. Of course my system is configured for Hungarian layout)

The language truly is irrelevant, I guess everyone having non-English keyboards might face similar problems. So how you work yourself around these?

Comment: suggestion,  apply normal US keyboard layout on your system, if you need type special letters in vim, use `ctrl-k`. before I bought my external keyboard, I worked everyday with German Keyboard, but the keyboard layout was always set to generic 101 or English (US).  of course, this requires you have the US layout in mind, and blind typing for all key combinations.

Comment: Eh, I guess this wouldn't work for me. I am also involved in projects maintained in Hungarian, and I also like writing (I don't say I am a writer, just like pretending to try) in my native language. I can do these both with mcedit (even more so since I could set up the system for UTF-8 quite a while ago). So I actually have an intention on whether I could replace mcedit favouring vim if I figured out and liked it's concept (not just because git would like so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap all vim defaults bindings with the `map` function.
For further information, [you can read this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)

Answer (score 4):

Look at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/keymap/` directory *(in debian/ubuntu it is a part of the `vim-runtime` package)*, you should see a bunch of keymap files for different locales. Chose the one you like. In the example I use `russian-jcukenwin.vim`.

Add to your *.vimrc* file →

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
set iminsert=0
set imsearch=0
highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Cyan
```

Now you can switch layout with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> keys. Note: layout is switchable when in *insert-mode*.

As you can guess the first line is the name of the file I mentioned. The next two lines sets the *iminsert* and *imsearch* in order to start writing the very first time with latin layout. In fact <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> toggles them between 1 and 0. And the last line draws the caret with cyan color when layout is changed.

Comment: For me on Windows Ctrl-^ draws ^^ in the search line instead of switching layout. Fixed with setting imsearch to 1. Don't know how but it works.

Answer (score 0):

## simple solution

you can switch to English layout when using vim:

`setxkbmap us`

and switch back to hungarian keyboard (`hu`) afterwards.

## xkb

To show you another way:

the xkeyboard layout for `hu` keyboard is located in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/hu`. Try to compare the layout with `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`.

There are also layout variants for `hu` keyboard than just `default`.
See [my post here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002792/712203)

If you want to do something advanced, you could also apply the english keyboard to the <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> modifier `LEVEL`